# Numpy array copy slower than Python list copy

Tags: python, list, numpy, performance

I've seen several posts here about accessing individual items in numpy arrays and python lists via a for loop.

My program is a little different.  What I'm doing is copying a small array (or list) of about 10 elements and then using it.  I'm doing this many times, so I want it to be fast.  The application if you're interested is that I'm searching a tree, and each small array/list is a 'state' in the tree.

But I'm finding that the `numpy.copy()` function is slower than the Python `list()` function.

To demonstrate what I'm saying, here's a small program with timings:

```
import time

import numpy as np
def numPyArrays(iterations:int):

    initialArray = np.array([1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0])

    for i in range(iterations):
        nextArray = initialArray.copy()
    
    print(f"Numpy Arrays:\n{nextArray}")
    return    

def pythonLists(iterations:int):

    initialList = [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]

    for i in range(iterations):
        nextList = list(initialList)
    
    print(f"Python Lists:\n{nextList}")
    return

def main():

    numIterations = 10000000

    startTime = time.time()
    numPyArrays(numIterations)
    print(f"Time taken: {round(time.time() - startTime, 2)} seconds.\n")

    startTime = time.time()
    pythonLists(numIterations)
    print(f"Time taken: {round(time.time() - startTime, 2)} seconds.\n")

main()
```

Timings:

```
Numpy Arrays:
[1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
Time taken: 4.68 seconds.

Python Lists:
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Time taken: 1.5 seconds.
```

I would have thought the numpy.copy function would have been as fast as a list copy.

EDIT: For those wanting to know what the underlying problem is, it's an Advent of Code problem.  Day 19, 2022.  `https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/19`

Comment: Is this just an observation or do you have any *specific* question about it?

Comment: I guess my specific question is about why creating a numpy array and copying over some contents of another array into it, takes so much longer than doing the same thing with a list.

Comment: Creating a new `np.array` takes more time than creating a new `list`. With 10 elements, mainly the effort required for this is measured. Compare your benchmark with arrays/lists of size 1, 10 (no measurable difference between 1 and 10), 100, 1000, 10000.

Comment: First off, don't write your own timing code. There are many things wrong with this benchmarking setup, all of which are trivially avoided by *not writing a script at all* and simply using the standard library `timeit` module at the command line.

Comment: For example, the Numpy code can be tested like: `python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np" -s "i = np.array([1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0])" -- "i.copy()"`, and the plain list code like: `python -m timeit -s "i = [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]" -- "list(i)"`. Incidentally, that's neither the fastest nor the most idiomatic way to do the list copy.

Comment: I suspect you have an XY problem. Numpy is for doing stuff with arrays. If you make a Python tree with Numpy arrays as the nodes it's unlikely that you'll get any speed benefit from Numpy. OTOH, if it's a simple binary tree, you can efficiently "pack" it into an array, similar to what heapq does. https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html

Comment: I reopened this.  I think our answers provide a more focused response than the link.  And comments suggest there's more to the question than simply copying.  But maybe that's a topic for a new question.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys, I do find this really interesting and helpful. @PM 2Ring, your comments re the tree are helpful, unfortunately it's not a binary tree.  But I am looking into just allocating one big numpy array up front, that can hold enough states for the search, and using those over and over again.  So the copy will still take place many times, but the array creation only once.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, I'll look into the argument you make about timing.  I do note though that either way, you get the same results.  Genuine question: I'd be interested to know what the 'many things wrong' are? Like, why is it better to use timeit, and not the time module?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, I have read about time vs timeit - you're right, timeit seems to be the better way to go.  But I often want to time a whole script i.e. the execution of something that might be say 150 lines and take maybe 45 minutes.  I'd use the time library for that right?

Comment: @davo36 Sure, you can write your own timing code, but you have to be careful, otherwise you may end up not timing what you think you're timing. As the timeit docs say "It avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution times". But even when using timeit you need to make decisions appropriate for the task that you're timing. Generally, you should use `time.perf_counter()` (or maybe `time.process_time()`) rather than `time.time()`. The random nature of GC (garbage collection) can interfere with timing, so timeit temporarily disables GC by default.

Comment: @hpaulj Fair enough. The linked dupe target does have good info about the speed of creation of Numpy arrays vs lists, but it is a bit antiquated, with inconvenient Python 2 `print` statements. I agree that array vs list speed isn't very relevant to davo36's underlying problem, but that's a topic for a different question.

Comment: "often want to time a whole script" If there's a main function and you're actually timing a call to that, `python -m timeit -s "import script" -- "script.main()"` should work fine. If all the code is at top level, it's definitely trickier, but it will be trickier regardless. `timeit` also has a programmatic API, although IMO it's not as good as it can be (I have an old project with some improvements).

Comment: @hpaulj " I think our answers provide a more focused response than the link" - I don't follow. The question here is about something less focused: the overall copy process. The bottleneck is the instantiation of Numpy arrays, and the other question is about specifically that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ipython timeit

```
In [82]: %%timeit x= [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
    ...: list(x)
185 ns ± 1.97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

another way of making a copy of a list:

```
In [83]: %%timeit x= [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
    ...: z=x[:]
146 ns ± 1.98 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

A list consists of a databuffer that holds references to the list objects (plus a small growth space).  These copies make a new list, with simple copy of that databuffer.   Same references.

The array copy, as you note is slower, but I consider any timeit measured in `ns` to be trivially fast.

```
In [84]: %%timeit x=np.array([1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0])
    ...: x.copy()
756 ns ± 2.74 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

But let's look at a larger array/list:

```
In [88]: %%timeit x=np.arange(10000)
    ...: x.copy()
5.37 µs ± 8.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [89]: %%timeit x= list(range(10000))
    ...: x[:]
40.4 µs ± 100 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The array copy scales better.  That means that a large part of the difference you saw has to do higher "startup" cost in the array copy.  The copy per element is faster.

In general, operations on small lists often are faster than similar ones with arrays.  It's when the length gets large(r) that the arrays are advantageous.  But don't just go by speed; what you are doing with the list or array is just as important.

### edit

Let's look at what tweaking a few values does to the times

```
In [97]: %%timeit x= list(range(10))
    ...: y=x[:]; y[3] = 4; y[1]=0
243 ns ± 2.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [98]: %%timeit x=np.arange(10)
    ...: y=x.copy(); y[[3,1]] =[4,0]
9.89 µs ± 15.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Even though the list tweaking has to be done one by one, it's still faster.  In fact accessing individual items adds substantially to the time.

This addition doesn't change the times for the large example.  There the copying, for both, dominates the times.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all this.  I'm basically coming to the idea that I need to allocated memory upfront for my states.  And then just use that memory over and over again.  Something like this `globalStateList = np.zeros((MAX_STATES, 10), dtype = int)` where `MAX_STATES` is some number large enough to hold all the states in my search tree.

Answer (score 1):

The operation your doing seems pointless, you just assign the same array or list to a new variable over and over and over. What happens if you actually make that many copies of the data in a useful manner?

How about this:

```
import time

import numpy as np


def numPyArrays(iterations: int):
    initialArray = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])

    result = np.zeros((iterations, len(initialArray)), dtype=int)
    result[:, :] = initialArray

    print(result[0], result[1], result[-1])
    return


def pythonLists(iterations: int):
    initialList = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

    result = [list(initialList) for i in range(iterations)]

    print(result[0], result[1], result[-1])
    return


def main():
    numIterations = 10000000

    startTime = time.time()
    numPyArrays(numIterations)
    print(f"Time taken: {round(time.time() - startTime, 2)} seconds.\n")

    startTime = time.time()
    pythonLists(numIterations)
    print(f"Time taken: {round(time.time() - startTime, 2)} seconds.\n")


main()
```

Result:

```
[1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0] [1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0] [1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
Time taken: 0.13 seconds.

[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Time taken: 4.26 seconds.
```

All your example shows is that initialising an entirely new `numpy` array has some overhead compared to defining a new list. But in any realistic scenario, you'd only do that a few times anyway, while the copy operation itself is *way* faster in `numpy`, as this example shows.

Instead of copying the same array over and over to a completely new array, my code copies the array to a new row of an array that many times. And then it does the same with lists. Here, `numpy` is more than an order of magnitude faster.

(Note that my example just prints the first 2 and then the last copy of each result, but of course that's arbitary - you can write some code to check that all rows do in fact have the same values assigned)

Comment: Yes I know my program doesn't do anything useful, I was just highlighting the problem I'm having.  As I said, I'm doing a tree search, and so need to be able to create these states (which can be arrays or lists or even classes with integer data members). And to create a state's children, I need to be able to create new child states and add them onto a stack for a DFS search.

Which means I need to create a new state somehow and change a couple of numbers in it, reflecting that new state.

I might be able to use what you have done here, which is really allocating a lot of memory up front.

Comment: So it's the new array creation that is slow compared to creating a new list.  Not the copying over of the data...

Comment: Per my own timing results, creating a new, **empty** Numpy array takes about as long as making the copy. That's where basically all the work goes.

Comment: How are you using the states?  Looking at specific values, or doing math and other numpy array things?  A test that includes' tweaking a few values, and doing some sort of state test would be more realistic than just copy.

Comment: @hpaulj, with the states, I'm just setting a few values in the state, that's all I need to do.  That represents the new state. So for instance I might take a [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] state and one of it's children might be [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] - so the exact same thing, but with a 1 at the end.  That then goes onto the stack and gets used a bit later.

Comment: Either you need all the states (and allocate the memory and do something similar as shown here), or you don't need all the states (and you can just overwrite previous positions, or use multiple arrays). But since you're not really telling us anything about what your actual problem is, there's no real way to help. I've demonstrated that your point about lists being faster was due to an assumption about numpy that's based on the idea that you have to create a large number of arrays - that's likely not true, but what the best solution is requires knowing more about your problem.

Comment: Anyways, it sounds like lists are just fine for you.  Arrays don't have any advantage, speed or 'calculation' convenience.  And I doubt if the 'list copy' is a major time consumer, but you might have to do some sort of profiling to be sure.

Comment: @Grismar, the reason I didn't post the actual problem is that I've done this in the past and the first thing people say is "That's a bad way to solve that problem, don't do it that way" or "Why are you telling us your whole problem here , this is a question and answer forum we don't want the whole story, just ask your question"  I actually hate posting questions on StackOverflow, I often get voted down or flamed.

Comment: EDIT: For those wanting to know what the underlying problem is, it's an Advent of Code problem.  Day 19, 2022.  `https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/19`

Comment: That's OK, no offense was intended - I just wanted to make it clear that you need to tell us more about the actual problem (or some aspect of the problem you consider critical) for us to tell you whether you're right (lists would be better) or whether there's actually a better or more efficient way to use `numpy` to resolve it. I'll have a quick look at that problem though, and see what it's about.

Comment: From having looked at that problem, it's unclear how the question you asked is directly relevant - but as indicated in both my answer and hpaulj's accepted one, it's really just the overhead of creating arrays that explains the time difference, regardless of whether it truly matters in a solution.

Comment: @Grismar, well this problem is usually solved via a tree search.  You start of with 1 ore and 1 ore robot.  You then have to make a series of moves to get to minute 24 creating the max no. of geodes possible.  Each node in the tree has a certain number of resources (4 ints) and no. of robots (4 ints) plus the minute it's at (1 int).  So 9 ints actually.  I made it 10 in my post above, just for simplicity.  I was using a class for each node but I realised the class is just 9 ints, so wondered if lists or arrays would be simpler and faster.